# Call to a member function header() on null in Cors Middleware in lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

[image]

hello everyone. I have cors middleware in my lumen as above. cors midlleware works normally when i make a request to lumen from my app. however, whenever a function that I need to send mail runs, I get the error "Call to a member function header() on null".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Due to the middleware structure, it returns and switches to the next request after processing. If an error is encountered after the request middleware has passed and did not return, the return value will be null.

For example, after I pass the request from the cors middleware, I am sending a mail via  a  event as a result of a series of operations. However, even though I changed the mail blade I sent, the cors middleware response value returns null because the php document created in ~/storage/framework/views does not update, and an error occurs.